# Sampling rows with specific criteria

Tags: permutation, sample

I am trying to create some sort of a schedule for me and my flatmates, but I am not sure how to do it, hell I am not even sure if it is feasible.

A simplified version of what I am trying to do is: let's assume that we have 5 individuals (John, Mike, Jack, Collin and Anna) and 3 chores (1, 2, 3). I want to spread these chores among the individuals, while a couple of criteria are being fulfilled. For example, each individual must do chore #1 two times per month.

I am really shooting in the dark here, and I am not sure how to approach this problem. So far I have used permutation to find all the possible combinations between the chores, and then I apply the criteria with a couple of loops. Here is the code:

```
####################
#install.packages("gtools")
library(gtools)
maat=permutations(3, 4, repeats.allowed = T)#Finding all the possible combinations of the chores for 4 weeks and 3 chores.
#The following loop applies two criteria: #
#1) in a 4-week period (1 month) chore #1 must be done two times
#2) in a 4-week period all of the chores must be done at least one
o=k=0
for (i in 1:nrow(maat)) {
  if ((sum(maat[i,] %in% 1) == 2) &&  all(1:3 %in% maat[i,])) {
    o[k]=i
    k = k + 1}
}
newmaat<-maat[o,] #the filtered matrix

cleaningRot<-matrix(ncol=4, nrow=5
      , data=newmaat[sample(nrow(newmaat), size=5, replace=F),]
      ,  dimnames = list(c("John", "Mike", "Jack", "Collin", "Anna")
      , c(paste0("Week",1:4)))) # This is the schedule for each individual
##The following loop applies 2 more criteria:
#1) all three chores must be done per week
#2) each week chores #1 and #2 must be done twice
while(!all(1:3 %in% cleaningRot[,1])| #All three chores must be in the 1st week
      !all(1:3 %in% cleaningRot[,2])| #All three chores must be in the 2st week
      !all(1:3 %in% cleaningRot[,3])| #All three chores must be in the 3st week
      !all(1:3 %in% cleaningRot[,4])  #All three chores must be in the 4st week
      |
      !(sum(cleaningRot[,1] %in% 1) == 2) && !(sum(cleaningRot[,1] %in% 2) == 2)| #Chores #1 and #2 must be done 2 times in week 1
      !(sum(cleaningRot[,2] %in% 1) == 2) && !(sum(cleaningRot[,2] %in% 2) == 2)|#Chores #1 and #2 must be done 2 times in week 2
      !(sum(cleaningRot[,3] %in% 1) == 2) && !(sum(cleaningRot[,3] %in% 2) == 2)|#Chores #1 and #2 must be done 2 times in week 3
      !(sum(cleaningRot[,4] %in% 1) == 2) && !(sum(cleaningRot[,4] %in% 2) == 2)#Chores #1 and #2 must be done 2 times in week 4

  ){
  cleaningRot<-matrix(ncol=4, nrow=5, data=newmaat[sample(nrow(newmaat), size=5, replace=F),],
                      dimnames = list(c("John", "Mike", "Jack", "Collin", "Anna"), c(paste0("Week", 1:4))))
}


 ######################################
```

So, basically, I am sampling between the permutations until the result fulfil the given assumptions; a highly random method, but my programming knowledge doesn't allow me to do more.

Another problem of this approach is that if the number of chores/individuals/weeks are bigger, it is almost impossible to randomly find the suitable schedule given the assumptions.

So my question is if you know a more methodical way to do that, rather than just sampling randomly from a pool of numbers?

Thank you and apologies for my messy code.

Comment: Could you explicitly list and clarify all of your criteria? I'm a little confused because you mention that one of your criteria is that `in a 4-week period (1 month) chore #1 must be done two times` then you have `each week chores #1 and #2 must be done twice`.  Isn't the first criteria unnecessary? Same thing for your other criteria (i.e. the weekly constraints will take care of your 4-week constraints).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Joseph. So the criteria for the current schedule are as follows:

**Chores_Weekly:**
1) chores 1# and 2# must be done two times per week.
2) All three chores must be done pew week

**Individuals_Monthly:**
1) Each individual must do chores 2# and #3 one time during the 4-week period
2) Each individual must do chore #1 two times during the 4-week period

This is an small example of what I am doing. My normal data are quite larger (8 individuals, 8 weeks, 6 chores), and more well-defined.

Comment: With the conditions you listed, there is no solution. Proof: You have 5 people doing only single chore once per week. Chores #1 & #2 must be performed twice per week, while all of them must be performed at least once.  This implies that 2 people will perform chore #1 and 2 people will perform chore #2, leaving the last individual performing chore #3 every week. Over a four week span, chores #1 & #2 will be performed exactly 8 times each.  If each individual must perform chore #1 twice over a 4 week span, then it would need to be performed 10 times ==> <== (contradiction).

Comment: Please correct me if I have missed something.... I was beginning to think that there was no solution yesterday when I ran your code and it would not terminate.

Comment: Yes you're right, with the given criteria there is no solution. As  I said, this is just a toy-example of what I am doing. But my question doesn't regard this example, I am not interested in whether these criteria are valid for the current paradigm. Instead, what I want to know is if there is another way, other than sampling randomly between numbers, that could help me find the correct combination of the given numbers. Anyway, I think what I am asking is not valid in general, I appreciate your help though.

Comment: To answer your previous comment, yes there is a much better approach. You can first generate all permutations of a multiset that satisfy your weekly conditions and then select a set of permutations that satisfy your long term conditions. I already have written a partial solution that I could post if you’d like.

Comment: That would be great, thanks! I have done some progress my self, I have transited from the random, aimless search to a more methodical one. In particular, what I've done is to find all the permutations of the weekly cycle (ie., rows; more or less what you've done yourself) and then choose which rows fulfil my monthly conditions and merge them, one-by-one, to a matrix; i.e., the cleaning rota.  The shortcoming of this approach is that is computationally expensive (I am getting errors saying: node stack overflow), and that I cannot apply all of the monthly conditions.